# How to find the date of the first day of week given any date range of that week in vb6

Tags: vb6, asp-classic

How do I find the date of the first day of week given any date of current week in vb6 or classic asp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Weekday(date)`

This returns an int between 1 and 7 for sun to sat. With this it is easy to get the date of the first day, but first you need to define the first day, assuming sunday then...

`DateAdd("d", -Weekday(date)+1, date)`

Comment: +1 Here are links to the VB6 reference manual topics for those two functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263404(v=VS.60).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262710(v=VS.60).aspx